# Avidemux shows better preview than VLC player

Tags: video, video-quality, dslr, nikon

I shot a video in Nikon D3400 and tried to play in VLC and native player of Ubuntu. But Avidemux preview is much greater than any of these two. Any way to get the quality of that preview for my video.

Do I need to do any editing to video to get that quality? I will put two images of the two video for comparison. [Avidemux-image](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1To-cRfp74k5D-bEOIMXmIoZSHz8cOHKv), [VLC-preview](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1a9x31WcbneGPOC0q9tfu3w_sph1pNfaw).

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a color space mismatch. You could be viewing a “clamped” (16-235) signal in VLC. This is a common issue with nVidia graphics cards.

See [VSG:Video:Color washed out](https://wiki.videolan.org/VSG:Video:Color_washed_out/).

Comment: No, I think youtube also giving same colored video